# GPU gave 3 Eth in 3 weeks, then added another GPU and no ETH after 1.5 weeks?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethminer, gpu, difficulty

I got the first 3 Eth in 3 weeks and then I decided to add another card (RX480s).

I stopped the mining (CTRL - C)
Then stopped geth node (CTRL - C)
Shutdown PC and installed extra GPU.
Ran geth test run for GPU and got double hash rate, cool.
Ran geth node and let it sync, I waited till it was updating by 1 block and the block number matched/exceeded number form eth stats.
Then ran GPU mining and waited...

It's been more than 4 weeks, and still no more ETH.
I'm worried I'm mining to "no where" ...

Is it just that difficulty has increased (exponentially) or I've done something wrong?

Comment: Hi there. You might want to run your specs through a mining calculator to see what your current expectations should be: https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mining on yor own you should be aware that finding a block solution is statistical in nature. Each new block is like flipping a coin again, with your hash power/total network hash power begin your odds.

Perhaps you were lucky and got 3 Ethers and now are unlucky and got nothing for 4 weeks.

Miners bunch together in pools, so there's more chance to mine a block and share the rewards between them, so profits are more predictable.